# Mass, Chamber pressure and cooling type of Rutherford Engine

Tags: rocketlab, turbopump, composite-materials, rutherford-engine, pressure

What are the specifications of Rocket Lab's [Rutherford Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_(rocket_engine)) used by the [Electron Rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(rocket))?

I'm looking for the chamber pressure, propellant mass flow rate, type of cooling for the nozzle, size of turbopump, dimension and mass of complete engine.

If possible, it would be interesting to also know if the materials used for nozzle, pump casing and seals was publicly available as well.

Comment: Thank you @uhoh for the editing. I am fairly new to the platform so I face formatting issue. And I'll try to follow it in the later questions. :)

Comment: Thanks allot! 
But please give some reasoning, like how are you guesstimating the values.

Comment: @Christoph, I guess based on Summerfeld criterion, they might Pe as 0.4 bar.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia page has a engine mass value of 35 kg, but its not references anywhere, so I would take that value with a pinch of salt. Some aspects of an electric pump fed engine are discussed in the thesis below, and may answer some of your questions, but no information has been officially released and available on the public domain.

https://www.aacademica.org/hernan.emilio.tacca/9.pdf